# removing the &gt; from a list by identifying the proper textnode with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textnode

I asked a somewhat similar question this afternoon and then realized as great as the answer is my question was not correct...

given the following:

```
<p class="p"> 
<div> </div> 
<div>
<a href="foo"> a </a>  &gt;
<a href="foo1"> b </a> 
<a href="foo2"> c</a> 
<a href="foo3"> b </a>  &gt;
<a href="foo4"> c </a> 
</div>
</p>
```

I need to remove the "&gt"` from the page as well as the a tag that precedes it. This is a dynamic list so it will continously grow over time. I need to someone latch onto the ">" remove it and then remove the a tag before it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. The `<div>` elements are going to be kicked out of the `<p>`.

After correcting your markup, you could do this:

```
var els = $('.p');

do {
    els.contents().each(function(i,el) {
        if( el.nodeType === 3 && $.trim( el.data ) === '>' ) {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el.previousSibling);
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    });
} while( ( els = els.children() ).length )
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GYUF3/1/)**

---

Or with a little more jQuery:

```
var els = $('.p');

do {
    els.contents().each(function(i,el) {
        if( el.nodeType === 3 && $.trim( el.data ) === '>' ) {
            $(el.previousSibling).remove();
            $(el).remove();
        }
    });
} while( ( els = els.children() ).length )
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GYUF3/2/)**

---

Or this:

```
var els = $('.p');

do {
    els.contents().each(function(i,el) {
        if( el.nodeType === 3 && $.trim( el.data ) === '>' ) {
            $(el.previousSibling).add(el).remove();
        }
    });
} while( ( els = els.children() ).length )
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GYUF3/3/)**